# R data.table fast way to append total of columns when doing aggregations across categories?

Tags: r, data.table

I constantly find myself adding a "total" row at the bottom of a data table aggregation.    Usually the total is just a sum down the columns.

This is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

```
DT = data.table(t = rep(as.Date(c("2018-05-01", "2018-07-01"))), 
                x=rep(c("b","a","c", "d"),each=5), y=rep(c(1,3,6, 5, 5), 4), v=1:20)

DT.agg <- DT[, .(y = sum(y), v = sum(v)), by = .(t, x)]
DT.agg

DT.agg
# t x  y  v
# 1: 2018-05-01 b 12  9
# 2: 2018-07-01 b  8  6
# 3: 2018-07-01 a 12 24
# 4: 2018-05-01 a  8 16
# 5: 2018-05-01 c 12 39
# 6: 2018-07-01 c  8 26
# 7: 2018-07-01 d 12 54
# 8: 2018-05-01 d  8 36
```

Now here comes the question.  Is there a quick an efficient way for adding the "sum total" in this aggregation?  I regularly just do this, when running R interactively and exploring multiple aggregations of the data quickly (but it takes several extra lines of code, annoyingly):

```
DT.tot <- DT[, .(x = "total", y = sum(y), v = sum(v)), by = t]
DT.agg2 <- rbind(DT.agg, DT.tot)

DT.agg2
# t     x  y   v
# 1: 2018-05-01     b 12   9
# 2: 2018-07-01     b  8   6
# 3: 2018-07-01     a 12  24
# 4: 2018-05-01     a  8  16
# 5: 2018-05-01     c 12  39
# 6: 2018-07-01     c  8  26
# 7: 2018-07-01     d 12  54
# 8: 2018-05-01     d  8  36
# 9: 2018-05-01 total 40 100
# 10: 2018-07-01 total 40 110
```

Is there a quick way, or a smarter way, to obtain `DT.agg2` without explicitly building the total and rbinding, that I might have overlooked?

I want the total because ultimately I want to compute things like this, what percentage of y is in category "a", etc:

```
DT.c <- dcast(DT.agg2, t ~ x, value.var = c("y", "v"))
# 
DT.c[, pct_y_a := y_a / y_total]

DT.c
#            t y_a y_b y_c y_d y_total v_a v_b v_c v_d v_total pct_y_a
#1: 2018-05-01   8  12  12   8      40  16   9  39  36     100     0.2
#2: 2018-07-01  12   8   8  12      40  24   6  26  54     110     0.3
```

Comment: I don't understand why this needs to be appended to the data.table for data exploration. Appending rows is inherently inefficient. It would be much better to calculate the percentages in long format.

Comment: Take a look at the new data.table functions `rollup`, `cube` and `groupingsets`. Perhaps that is of interest

Comment: @Roland Because sometime there are 10-20 rows in the summary.  casting them in long format looks ugly and/or goes off the page for the analysis.  It doesnt matter if the rbind operation is inefficient in the summary , from a practical perspective, if the summary only has 10-50 rows (say)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rollup` calculates aggregates at various levels of groupings producing multiple totals(/subtotals):

```
library(data.table)  # I'm using version 1.11.4
rollup(DT, j = lapply(.SD, sum), by = c("t", "x"))
#             t      x     y     v
#        <Date> <char> <num> <int>
# 1: 2018-05-01      b    12     9
# 2: 2018-07-01      b     8     6
# 3: 2018-07-01      a    12    24
# 4: 2018-05-01      a     8    16
# 5: 2018-05-01      c    12    39
# 6: 2018-07-01      c     8    26
# 7: 2018-07-01      d    12    54
# 8: 2018-05-01      d     8    36
# 9: 2018-05-01   <NA>    40   100    # <- total for date 2018-05-01
#10: 2018-07-01   <NA>    40   110    # <- total for date 2018-07-01
#11:       <NA>   <NA>    80   210    # <- grand total
```

The help file for `rollup` states:

> Calculate aggregates at various levels of groupings producing multiple (sub-)totals. Reflects SQLs GROUPING SETS operations.

Comment: Great!  This is pretty much what i'm looking for.

Comment: Nice, but how do you name directly the column x for the total instead of having <NA>?